# How to drop duplicates in first column and output values in 2nd column?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a tab-separated CSV file like this

```
C1      C2
A       3
B       4
C       5
B       4
A       3
```

How can I get rid of duplicates in col 1 and output the values from col 2 for each unique col1 value? Example output:

```
3
4
5
```

I've tried `awk -F '\t' '{print $1}' file_name.csv | sort | uniq -c` which sorts the data in the first column and 'drops' duplicates but this gets rid of column 2. I'm just a beginner to shell scripting so any help will do.

Comment: hi llamar25, is your CSV file formatted like that or is it comma-separated?

Comment: @BakaKuna it's tab separated. I just drew the table to make it easier to visualise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -F '\t' 'NR>1 && !seen[$1]++{print $2}' file_name.csv
```

- `NR>1` is false for first line, then it is skipped.
- `!seen[$1]++` is only 1 (or *true*) for a 1st field value that has been parsed for the first time (duplicates evaluate to 0, or *false*).
- `print $2` prints the 2nd field if both conditions were met.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the first two columns, you could use:

```
awk -F '\t' '!seen[$1]++{print $2}' testfile
```

Comment: And notice this does not get rid of duplicates, but it rather prints every duplicate, even though for the sample file, it's all the same.

Comment: @roaima: Right! I forgot to remove the first column.

Comment: @Quasímodo: Thanks, I must have copy pasted the wrong line.

Answer (score 1):

A non `awk` version using your `sort` and `uniq`

```
tail -n +2 file | sort -ugk2 | column -t -H 1
```

lose the header by printing the `tail` from line `-n`umber `+2` of the `file`

```
tail -n +2 file |
```

`sort` `-u`nique using `-g`eneral numeric on `-k`ey`2`

```
sort -ugk2 |
```

and output as `column`ar `-t`able but `-H`ide column `1`

```
column -t -H 1
```

Answer (score 0):

[Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html) has a groupwise `head` that allows you to take the first *n* records matching a particular column value (in this case, *n=1*):

```
$ mlr --tsv head -g C1 -n 1 then cut -f C2 file.tsv
C2
3
4
5
```

If you don't want the column headers, keep the `tsv` input format but change the output format to indexed:

```
mlr --itsv --onidx head -g C1 -n 1 then cut -f C2 file.tsv
```